# featured snippet and knowledge graph

Tags: google-custom-search

In google search we get the featured snippet box . For example if we search "what is the difference between solid and liquid?", It provides the matching answer in featured snippet. If you try Google Assistant  it reads out the content from featured snippet. But when i do through Custom search API I am not able to get the featured snippets and Knowledge Cards in the response Json.Does anybody help us how to get the featured snippets through Rest APIs.
Some times I am getting empty result from knowledge graph.

Comment: got anything on this?